# Visual Studio: cannot attach to process

Tags: visual-studio, office-js, office-addins

I want to debug a powerpoint office-js add-in to find out why the button is not working correctly.

However, I cannot attach to the iexplore.exe that executes the add-in; it is greyed out in the "Attach to process" list of my Visual Studio 2017:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8XG6.png

Why is this and how can I attach to the process for debugging?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the configuration? Is this an VS Office project? What edition of PPT is this running on?

Comment: It's this one: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO/ running on PowerPoint 2016 Version 1705 (Build 8201.2200 Click-and-run), with Update Check telling me that I am already on the newest version.

Comment: That add-in requires Office 2016, Version 1708, build 8424.nnnn or later. See the Prerequisites section of the readme.